# PHP try-catch not recognized on command-line? (Trying to install Composer)

Tags: php, try-catch, composer-php

I am trying to install Composer (http://getcomposer.org/download/) on a GoDaddy-hosted Linux server but it's not working.  No matter which method I try, I eventually run up against some version of the following error:

Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 290.

Line 290 refers to line 290 in this file: https://getcomposer.org/installer which is the start of a try-catch block.  And, indeed, even a simple script like:

```
echo '<?php echo "Hello World "; try {echo "Goodbye";} catch (Exception $e) {} ?>' | php
```

produces the same type of syntax error (forgive the awkward piping.  GoDaddy doesn't seem to like the -r option).

Similarly, if I put that code in a file "argh.php" and run `php -f argh.php` I get a syntax error, but it will work just fine if I visit the page in my browser.

Does anybody know why php keeps choking on the try-catch block OR any other way I can install Composer? (P.S., I am using PHP 5.3)

Comment: Works perfectly for my on my linux box.. Albeit it's not GoDaddy Hosted, I would check the PHP CLI configuration for any clues.

Comment: I think this is a problem with how you shell interprets single quotes.

Comment: @phpisuber01 Do you have any hints as to what I should be looking for? (Of course, searching for try, catch, exception, throw...all didn't work, that would be too easy :P)

Comment: @Jon I don't think that's the problem.  If I take the try-catch block out of the command I posted and just leave the Hello World part it works fine.

Comment: @Andrea: I does not sound to me that the problem is try/catch, but the brackets.

Comment: @Jon Well, yes, technically the brackets are the problem as the error message says, but if/else brackets, etc. work fine, so that suggests to me that the CLI isn't understanding the try keyword correctly and then gets confused when it sees a bracket after it.  Which to my mind means the problem is essentially with the try, not the bracket.  Am I on the wrong track?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running on that command line? There may be several different PHP executables, with `php` being some ancient version. (Though I couldn't say which ancient version would behave this way.)

Comment: @deceze Oh WHOA.  Okay, I'm an idiot.  GoDaddy let's you configure which version of PHP you're running your site on and I picked 5.3 but they've left the command line version as 4.4.9 for some lovely reason which, yeah, won't handle try-catch blocks.  (Random fact about GoDaddy, they've also disabled "which" so I had to blindly make assumptions about which php I was running from the command line and obviously I assumed wrong).  Well.  Dumb, dumb, dumb all around.

That solves the mystery, at least, although it doesn't get Composer installed from the command line :(

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<?php echo "Hello World "; try {echo "Goodbye";} catch (Exception $e) {} ?>' | /web/cgi-bin/php5
```

works just fine.  So I am just dumb.  I will try installing Composer using /web/cgi-bin/php5 now and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Since the hidden answer in the comments seems to get overlooked:

The `php` command on the command line is an old PHP version (4.x) which does not support the same syntax. The host may offer various PHP versions installed in parallel, with newer versions being available as `php5`, `php53`, `php5.3`, `/web/cgi-bin/php5` or some such alternative executable. Consult your host's documentation.